# Subdivision Surface Modifier has a red icon, and does not work

Tags: modifiers

My blender can´t make subdivision surface work, the icon shows red, the GPU subdivision message appears but I do have enabled GPU subdivision.

[image]

Comment: if you increase the width of the panel, what is the complete message that begins with "Autosmooth or custom ...."?  (please Edit your question, don't post a comment.)  You might also see this message if you display "Window >> Toggle System Console"

Answer (score 0):

Render Properties > Simplify ?
Check if on or off, this caught me out as well :D

[image]

Comment: OMGG, didn't know it was that simple, been struggling with that for weeks.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, it catches me out as well :D You are best to maybe turn it off and save start layout. Blender really need to trigger a warning system.